# What distribution would make a good hyper-prior for a Beta distribution parameterized by mean and sample size?

Tags: mixed-model, prior, beta-distribution

I have a model which includes a Beta distribution and I am looking for guidance on how to parameterize a hyper-prior for it.  For example, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539797/beta-distribution-with-a-priors-as-uniform-and-pareto-distribution) uses a Beta parameterized with a mean and concentration and takes the concentration `kappa ~ Pareto(1, 1.5)`.

What are some recommended distributions that I should consider for my kappa?  And what principles might I use to select the right one for my setting?

Comment: Another example of a hyper-prior distribution to a beta is given in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56319/how-to-derive-bayes-prior-given-large-amounts-of-sample-data-from-different-popu/56328#56328

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a uniform distribution with a lower bound selected to be not-too-low through trial and error:

```
kappa_s = numpyro.sample("kappa_s", dist.Uniform(5, 500))  # Model converges to unacceptable values when kappa_s is smaller (e.g. 1)
```

Comment: I won't accept this, but I though it might inspire someone to offer a more acceptable answer.